# how to find array count values,here i findout number of arrays but i want total array value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $tags =print_r (explode(",",$name));


  echo sizeof($tags);
}
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => j [1] => j [2] => j [3] => j ) 1
```

> here 1 is total array value but my arrays is 3!!

please solve this

Comment: There's so much wrong with this post. The formatting is horrible, the count of the array is 4 not 3, your `$tags` gets the return value of `print_r` which is true or false, unless you provide another parameter (see docs for print_r) then it is a string. and as Naresh mentions `count($array)` gives the number of entries in the array `$array`. and what the f* does this have to do with mysql, mysqli or phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

```
$tags =print_r (explode(",",$name));
```

You're assigning $tags to the return value from print_r().

Change it to this:

```
$tags = explode(",",$name);
print_r($tags);
echo count($tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

[print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) **prints** human-readable information about a variable, which should not be mixed with saving values in variable.

So your code should look like this,

```
$tags = explode(",",$name);
echo sizeof($tags);
```